# Check number of files in directory and if equal or more than 5 - remove the oldest one

Tags: cron, database-backups

I'm trying to create a cron job to create mysql backups. I would like to be able to first check how many files are there in the directory and if there are 5 or more remove one (the oldest) and create a new mysqldump. I know how to create the mysqldump, but not sure about the condition. I'm planning to store the procedure in the .sh file and trigger that file once a day with the cronjob.
Could someone show the example of what the procedure should look like?

Comment: And what your question is?

Comment: Just updated the question - with the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the following in a shell script

for file_to_delete in `ls -1ta test* | tail --lines=+6` ; do echo "ENTER_CMD_HERE $file_to_delete" ; done

where 
 - test is name of file (replace it with path + name of the mysql bkp files)
 - replace ENTER_CMD_HERE with say rm